# executing specific statement at a given rate in python

Tags: python

I want to write a code which execute a statement specified number of times per second,
Many of you might be familier about the term rate

Here i want rate to be 30 per second

say i want to execute a function 30 times per second for 60 seconds
means rate=30/sec duration=60sec

Can any one tell me is their any api available in python to do the same ?

Comment: It depends on how accurate it needs to be, which depends on why you are doing this.

Comment: If you want the functions to execute in parallel, then you need to state that up front before people waste time answering the wrong question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After some time spending i discovered how to do it well i used multiprocessing in python to achieve it 
here's my solution

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from multiprocessing import Process
import os
import time
import datetime
def sleeper(name, seconds):
   time.sleep(seconds)
   print "PNAME:- %s"%name


if __name__ == '__main__':
   pros={}
   processes=[]
   i=0
   time2=0
   time1=datetime.datetime.now()
   for sec in range(5):
        flag=0
        while flag!=1:
                time2=datetime.datetime.now()
                if (time2-time1).seconds==1:
                        time1=time2
                        flag=1
                        print "Executing Per second"
                        for no in range(5):
                                i+=1
                                pros[i] = Process(target=sleeper, args=("Thread-%d"%i, 1))
                        j=i-5
                        for no in range(5):
                                j+=1
                                pros[j].start()
                        j=i-5
                        for no in range(5):
                                j+=1
                                processes.append(pros[j])
   for p in processes:
        p.join()
```

Answer (score 2):

The `sched` module is intended for exactly this:

```
from __future__ import division
import sched
import time

scheduler = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)

def schedule_it(frequency, duration, callable, *args):
    no_of_events = int( duration / frequency )
    priority = 1 # not used, lets you assign execution order to events scheduled for the same time
    for i in xrange( no_of_events ):
        delay = i * frequency
        scheduler.enter( delay, priority, callable, args)

def printer(x):
    print x

# execute printer 30 times a second for 60 seconds
schedule_it(1/30, 60, printer, 'hello')
scheduler.run()
```

For a threaded environment, the use of `sched.scheduler` can be replaced by `threading.Timer`:

```
from __future__ import division
import time
import threading

def schedule_it(frequency, duration, callable, *args, **kwargs):
    no_of_events = int( duration / frequency )
    for i in xrange( no_of_events ):
        delay = i * frequency
        threading.Timer(delay, callable, args=args, kwargs=kwargs).start()

def printer(x):
    print x

schedule_it(5, 10, printer, 'hello')
```

Comment: For your threading.Timer example... you're resetting the timer every time this line is executed, so it will drift over time. Say you run it once a second for an hour, it should run 3600 times, but starting/stopping takes some time, so it will actually be less than 3600, and the drift will get worse over time. I'm looking for a way to maintain a frequency for perpetuity.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`threading.Timer`](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#timer-objects):

```
def hello():
    print "hello, world"

t = Timer(30.0, hello)
t.start() # after 30 seconds, "hello, world" will be printed
```

Comment: That's an example taken right from the linked docs. I think the guy can understand what he must do next :)

Comment: I'm downvoting this since it doesn't answer the question. The answer just shows how to run something with a delay, not at a fixed rate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `time.time()` to do what you want:

```
import time

def your_function():
    # do something...

while True:
    start = time.time() # gives current time in seconds since Jan 1, 1970 (in Unix)
    your_function()
    while True:
        current_time = time.time()
        if current_time - start >= 1.0/30.0:
            break
```

This will make sure that the delay between calls of `your_function` is very close to 1/30 of a second, even if `your_function` takes some time to run.

There is another way: using Pythons built-in scheduling module, `sched`. I never used it, so I can't help you there, but have a look at it.

Comment: Thanks for input , but this is not solving the problem as it take a pass from main to your_function and we dont know how much time it takes may be minutes , eg i put a sleep fn their. Nor this invoke many your_function at the same time

Comment: @user1471175 In that case I suggest you edit the question to clarify what you really want. You never mentioned the need for multiple processes in the first place.